# Filter a custom Listview using Buttons (Android)

Tags: android, listview, filter, android-adapter

I have a `Fragment` containing a custom `ListView` with custom `Adapter`. What I display in this list are some doctors which attributes are: `picture`, `name`, `age` and `gender`.

*What I would like to do is filter the doctors by `gender` when a button is pressed.* So that the default would display all doctors, a male button will display all males, and a female button all females. (as shown in the image below)

[image: Example in this image]

Here is my fragment code:

```
public class Doctors extends Fragment {


String[] names =  {"Richard Johnson", "William Perez", "Jennifer Fields", "Caroline Marin", "John Smith"};
String[] ages =  {"25", "32", "41", "31", "29"};
String[] gender = {"Male", "Male", "Female", "Female", "Male"};
int[] images = { R.drawable.delete_doctora,R.drawable.delete_doctora,R.drawable.delete_doctora,R.drawable.delete_doctora,R.drawable.delete_doctora,};

ListView list;
ArrayAdapter<DocItem> adapter;
ArrayList<DocItem> arrayList;


@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState){
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_doctors, container, false);

    arrayList = new ArrayList<DocItem>();

    for(int i = 0; i < 5; i++){
        arrayList.add(i,new DocItem(names[i], ages[i], gender[i], images[i]));
    }

    adapter = new DocAdapter(getActivity(), arrayList);
    list = (ListView) view.findViewById(R.id.ListDocs);

    list.setAdapter(adapter);
    list.setTextFilterEnabled(true);


    return view;
}

}
```

My custom Adapter:

```
public class DocAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<DocItem> {

private Context context;
private ArrayList<DocItem> _values;

public DocAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<DocItem> values) {
    super(context, 0, values);
    this.context = context;
    _values = new ArrayList<DocItem>();
    _values.addAll(values);
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context
            .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    View rowView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.doc_list_row, parent, false);
    TextView txtName = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.Name);
    TextView txtAge = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.Age);


    ImageView imageView = (ImageView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.Pic);
    txtName.setText(_values.get(position)._name);
    txtAge.setText(_values.get(position)._age);
    imageView.setImageResource(_values.get(position)._picture);

    return rowView;
}
}
```

And the Item:

```
public class DocItem {

public String _name, _age, _gender;
int _picture;

public DocItem(String name, String age, String gender, int picture){
    _name = name;
    _age = age;
    _picture= picture;
    _gender = gender;

}

}
```

Comment: What's your question, exactly? [ask]

Comment: how can I show only the men or women in my ListView when the respective button is pressed. using the value of 'gender' as a filter

Comment: use [this](https://gist.github.com/pskink/1cc7435461fee1c90d1ed311dd1c3e82) "ready for custom filters" array adapter

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use two arrays in the Adapter. Use one for storage and one for currently shown items.

```
private ArrayList<DocItem> all_values;         //All items
private ArrayList<DocItem> filter_values;    //Shown items

public DocAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<DocItem> values) {
    ...
    all_values = new ArrayList<DocItem>();
    all_values.addAll(values);
    filter_values = all_values.clone();
}    

...

 @Override
public int getCount() {
    return filter_values.size();
}

public void noFilter() {
    filter_values = all_values;
    notifyDataSetChanged();
}

public void filterMales() {
    filterGender("Male");
}

public void filterFemales() {
    filterGender("Female");
}

private void filterGender(String gender) {
    filter_values = new ArrayList<>();
    for(DocItem doc : all_values) {
       if(doc._gender.equals(gender)) {
           filter_values.add(doc);
       }
    }
notifyDataSetChanged();
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)     {
!!! USE filter_values array
}
```

Usage:

In your fragments onCreateView:

```
Button buttonMales = (Button) findViewById(R.id.filterMales);
Button buttonFemales = (Button) findViewById(R.id.filterFemales);

buttonMales.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        adapter.filterMales();
    }
});

buttonFemales.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
   @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        adapter.filterFemales();
    }
});
```

Comment: Not the most optimal solution but it should get the job done.

Comment: How do I access to the filterMales method from my Doctors class button?

Comment: @CarlosCampos Added usage example. You will also need to make the same for "All" button.

Comment: I tried, but I get an error telling me: cannot resolve method 'filterMales' :(

Comment: Yes I see your problem. Use `DocAdapter adapter` in your fragment instead of  `ArrayAdapter<DocItem> adapter`.

Comment: works perfect, Thanks :)
just had to add this to delete the empty Items:
@Override
    public int getCount(){
        return  filter_values.size();
    }